# How do I replace separator of breadcrumb in react-bootstrap using css?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

so I have a breadcrumb component that I've used with react-bootstrap. I need to override the default separator with ">". But it did not override anything. Could anyone help with this?

Breadcrumb:

```
<Breadcrumb>
   <Breadcrumb.Item onClick={goTo('/')}>Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
   <Breadcrumb.Item onClick={goTo(`/store`)}>
      {store?.name || 'unknown'}s
   </Breadcrumb.Item>
   <Breadcrumb.Item active>{title}</Breadcrumb.Item>
</Breadcrumb>
```

CSS:

```
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before { content: ">" !important; }
```

Answer (score 5):

.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before{content:var(--bs-breadcrumb-divider,">") !important ;}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
  content: "|" !important;
}
```

I am  using this code and its working

```
.breadcrumb-item {
  + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: ">" !important;
    align-self: baseline;
    color: #7d8daa;
  }
}
```

PS : Please make sure that there is no conflicting font-family to the selector else it might not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)
like that

```
import React from "react";
import { Breadcrumb } from "react-bootstrap";
import styled from "styled-components";
const StyledBreakcrumb = styled(Breadcrumb.Item)`
  &:not(:first-child):before {
    content: ">" !important;
  }
`;
function BreadcrumbBs() {
  return (
    <>
      <Breadcrumb>
        <StyledBreakcrumb href="www.google.com">Home</StyledBreakcrumb>
        <StyledBreakcrumb href="www.google.com">Library</StyledBreakcrumb>
        <StyledBreakcrumb active>Data</StyledBreakcrumb>
      </Breadcrumb>
    </>
  );
}

export default BreadcrumbBs;
```